# Eigenvalue calculation of a eigenfunction from a differential equation using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose, I have an differential equation like this one:

```
mu1 u1[x] - u1''[x] - 10 u1[x] == 0
```

where mu1 is the eigenvalue and u1 is the eigenfuntion. Now, How can i calculate the eigenvalue mu1 numerically??? Can anyone help me out with this problem??

Comment: I don't quite understand. Your solutions depend on `mu1` like `u1[x_]:= Ct E^(+/-)(Sqrt[-10 + mu1] x)`

Comment: Is u1 specified? As currently stated, I don't think this problem can be solved numerically. You may find [NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html) helpful but this is _not_ exactly the same thing you are looking for. Also see [Eigenvalues and vectors](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EigenvaluesAndEigenvectors.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to solve something like

```
u1''[x] + 10 u1[x] == mu1 u1[x]
```

with boundary conditions

```
u1[x0] == 0; u1[x1] == 0; u1'[x0] =!= 0
```

for some `x0 < x1`. One way to do that is to first solve the differential equation plus the boundary conditions at `x0`, e.g.

```
sol = DSolve[{mu1 u1[x] - u1''[x] - 10 u1[x] == 0, u1[x0] == 0, u1'[x0] == 1}, u1, x][[1]]
```

which gives as output

```
{u1 -> Function[{x}, -((E^(-Sqrt[-10 + mu1] x - Sqrt[-10 + mu1] x0) 
    (-E^(2 Sqrt[-10 + mu1] x) + E^(2 Sqrt[-10 + mu1] x0)))/(2 Sqrt[-10 + mu1]))]}
```

We can then use this solution to find `mu1` such that the boundary condition at `x1` is satisfied:

```
sol1 = Solve[{u1[x1] == 0 /. sol[[1]], x1 > x0}, mu1, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

From which we find

```
{{mu1 -> ConditionalExpression[(10 x0^2 - 20 x0 x1 + 10 x1^2 - 4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]^2)/(
     x0^2 - 2 x0 x1 + x1^2), 
    x0 \[Element] Reals && C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1 && x1 > x0]}, 
 {mu1 -> ConditionalExpression[(-\[Pi]^2 + 10 x0^2 - 20 x0 x1 + 10 x1^2 - 
     4 \[Pi]^2 C[1] - 4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]^2)/(x0^2 - 2 x0 x1 + x1^2), 
    x0 \[Element] Reals && C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0 && x1 > x0]}}
```